# System.Drawing.Printing is not available for windows server

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am doing a Windows service using visual studio 2012

I want that service to print something

I normally can print stuff, but in this case, I got that 
`System.Drawing.Printing` is not available

could you help me please

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {}
```

Comment: Do you have reference to `System.Drawing.dll` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel are you implying that I should add that reference please?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no I don't have that reference included.

Comment: Yes of course. You need to add it. Because `System.Drawing.Printing.XXX` exist in that assembly only.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel when I tried to add reference, there is no System.Drawing option

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no sorry there is. there are System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Design. should I add both of them or the former would be enough?

Comment: No only `System.Drawing` is enough latter is not required(AFAIK).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel and now when I register my service, should I do anything in order to add the reference? or this reference will be added automatically when registering the service?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. You can follow the regular deployment procedure which you are following now. This dll will be there in GAC so your program will get access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs` class live in `System.Drawing.dll` assembly. So you must add the reference to System.Drawing assembly in order to use it.

If you have the assembly reference in place and still you get the error? Please refer my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212438/2530848)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you need to have a reference to "ReachFramework" to make System.Printing.PrintTicket and System.Printing.PrintCapabilities

Comment: can you post some code? ... i think your answer its vague

Comment: It's a project setting.