# The type or namespace name could not be found (same .NET Frameworks)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have two projects which are both Class Libraries and are both running on .NET Framework 4. I am using VS2013.

For some reason the namespace of project A is not found in Project B.
At creation, project A had .NET Framework 4.5 but I revised this later on.

After this I encountered some other reference errors. I threw the references away and lay new ones.

I have only one left which is not going away.

There are more questions like this one, but the answers didn't helped me because both of my projects are running on the same .NET framework.

Comment: Does [this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211641/the-type-or-namespace-name-device-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system)? I'm not marking this as duplicate as you said related questions didn't answer your question. Did you clean and rebuild? Restarted VS ?

Comment: did you add the refrence of the Project A to B?

Comment: @sriramSakthivel I've already tried that.

Comment: @irfanTahirKheli Yes I did

Comment: I'm afraid anyone here could help you without seeing the problem. Almost all cases my answer in linked thread should help. If not, provide a sample project which doesn't work. We'll look into it.

Comment: You don't  maybe have an old version in the GAC?

Comment: What do you mean by GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.. so i finally fixed it.

In Project A I had a nugget package installed 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build'.
Apparently it is necessary for Project B to also have this nugget package to properly 'understand' the reference.

Lessons learned:
Allways look at your Warnings

Literature:
[Improved package restore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/12/improved-package-restore.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are couple things you need to make sure:

- the project containing the type is referenced in the project that uses that type (project -> references)
- you've got set the correct `using` in the file where you're using the type
- type has accessibility set to `public`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I've never said anything different.. All I did was to point out important things to look for when referencing a type from another assembly.

Comment: You're right but it is irrelevant to this question because OP says *The type or namespace name could not be found*. If type isn't public, you'd get Type isn't accessible or something like that. But, yes, I agree it has to be public.

Comment: All of the above are correct. I guess it's better to add a test project for all of you to see