# The type or namespace name 'ISet' does not exist

Tags: c#, nhibernate, smartclient, iesi-collections

I'm upgrading a Windows Smart Client solution from nHibernate 2.2 to 4.0.
This required updating Iesi.Collections (4.0.1.4000) as well.

On this line:

```
protected Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<PermitEvent> eventSet;
```

I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ISet' does not exist in the namespace 'Iesi.Collections.Generic'
```

This question has gone unanswered at 2 other sites:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/the-type-or-namespace-name-iset-could-not-be-found
http://www.resolvinghere.com/cc/the-type-or-namespace-name-iset-could-not-be-found.shtml

What can I do?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23211641/2530848)

Comment: In the past and because of these kinds of problems, I have used IEnumerable and IList instead of anything in Iesi.Collections.  I know that involves code changes (potentially many code changes), but might that be an option here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With NHibernate 4, in most cases you [do not need anymore to explicitly depend on Iesi](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/08/nh-4-ga).

You should instead migrate your entities code to use `System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`.

This is what I have done, even before encountering any issue with Iesi.
If you want to keep on using Iesi, you may be able to do that by supplying your own `NHibernate.Bytecode.ICollectionTypeFactory` with the [optional setting](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) `collectiontype.factory_class`. But I do not think it is worth the trouble.

[Release notes](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt), section "** Known BREAKING CHANGES from NH3.3.3.GA to 4.0.0.GA":

> Many uses of set types from Iesi.Collections have now been changed to use corresponding types from the BCL. The API for these types are slightly different.